# Jq Invalid numeric literal at EOF

Tags: json, jq

I'm try to add in a Json file a record structured for Raid info

```
jq '.raid.c0.e252.s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}' file.json
```

But I got 2 errors:

```
jq: error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 5 (while parsing '.e252') at <top-level>, line 1:
.raid.c0.e252.s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.raid.c0.e252.s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}
jq: 2 compile errors
```

After some tests, I understand that problem is field name. Apparently `e<number>` is not accepted.
in fact, using:

```
jq '.raid.c0.p252.s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}' file.json
```

or

```
jq '.raid.c0.eid252.s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}' file.json
```

in both case I got the expected results:

```
{
  "raid": {
    "c0": {
      "eid252": {
        "s0": {
          "device": "/c0/e252/s0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is clearly not a big problem, I can use any field name, but staring from device name `/c0/e252/s0` should be more simple to query `.c0.e252.s0`

jq version is 1.6 and I would like to keep the version present on official repo.

Someone know about a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: It seems a bit odd to have the structure named exactly like the `device` value. It's as if you are encoding the same value twice. It's usually easier to query structures that are not dependent on data ("look for the device name in the array of all devices"), or the other way around, it's harder to query structures that depend on the thing that you are looking for ("look for the device name in the structure named after the device name").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is happening due to how the value `e252` is being parsed.

It's being seen as exponent (`e252 = 10^252`), but this notation requires a leading number, such as `1e252 = 1x10^252`. The unexpected formatting is why you're getting the "Invalid numeric literal" parsing error.

Obviously, you're looking for the string literal of `e252`, so you should be able to use the following for what you're intending:

`jq '.raid.c0."e252".s0  +={"device": "/c0/e252/s0"}' < file.json`

which gives:

```
{
  "raid": {
    "c0": {
      "eid252": {
        "s0": {
          "device": "/c0/e252/s0"
        }
      },
      "e252": {
        "s0": {
          "device": "/c0/e252/s0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great first answer, welcome to U&LSE! :-)

Comment: There currently is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1526) relating to this.

Comment: I never thought it was an interpreted as a number, thanks. Someone knows for other "unsupported" fields name?